# ios frame and bounds - CGRectMake is offscreen

Tags: ios, ipad

On iPad following is offscreen when in portrait, why this even when starting up in portrait?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView* imageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    blue.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [[self view] addSubview:imageView];
```

I have been told that the root view's frame is always the same in portrait and landscape:
- portrait frame orign(x i representing the orign of an UIView)
x0
00
00

Landscape frame orign:
000
x00

But why is CGRectMake(0,0 .. not up in the right corner in portrait?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `bounds` are the same always, `frame` does change on rotations, etc. Also the origin is always the top left corner, independent you current device orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bounds and the frame can change when you rotate the device. Let's take a Single View Application template as an example, add orientation support and run it on the iPhone. In portrait:

```
bounds = (0, 0, 320, 460) // 460 compensates for 20p status bar
frame = (0, 20, 320, 460) // status bar adjustment
x0
00
00
```

In landscape:

```
bounds = (0, 0, 480, 300) // now 20p is taken from "height"
frame = (20, 0, 300, 480) // status bar adjustment
x00
000
```

Origin is always top-left corner, regardless of orientation.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad is always Portrait though & [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] is always Portrait